# Knockout - Unexpected identifier (SyntaxError: Unable to process binding)

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.5, knockout

I am getting the following error in the browser console:

```
knockout.js:2982 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unable to process binding "ifnot: function(){return customer().fullname }"
Message: Unable to parse bindings.
Bindings value: html:'Welcome To ________ Store'
Message: Unexpected identifier
    at new Function (<anonymous>)
```

This occurs in a template where the `$block` type is `Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Header`

`/var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-theme/Block/Html/Header.php` content has the `public function getWelcome()`

`/var/www/html/app/design/frontend/Sm/market/Magento_Theme/templates/html/header-style-2.phtml` returns `$block` as type described above.

It calls `<?php $welcomeMessage = $block->getWelcome(); ?>` at the start of the template, then later on: seems to bind here:

```
 <span class="greet welcome" data-bind="scope: 'customer'">
       <!-- ko if: customer().fullname  -->
           <span data-bind="text: new String('<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('W>
                                                                </span>
       </ko -->
       <!-- ko ifnot: customer().fullname  -->
             <span data-bind="html:'<?= $block->escapeHtml($welcomeMessage) ?>'"></>
       <!-- /ko -->
</span>
```

I am actually not sure what is wrong, or why Knockout cannot parse the bindings.
May you please assist, thanks!

#### Edit:

*Initially (above) I just added the sections of code that I 'thought' is applicable since it is related to knockout*, but full code was requested, so this makes the information long:

*This spans two files:* 'header.phtml' and 'header-style/header-2.phtml'

*header.phtml `include 'Magento_Theme::html/header-style/` . $headerStyle . '.phtml';*

> `app/design/frontend/Sm/market/Magento_Theme/templates/html/header.phtml`

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

/**
 * @var \Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Header $block
 */

$_config     = $this->helper('Sm\Market\Helper\Data');
$headerStyle = $_config->getThemeLayout('header_style');
include($block->getTemplateFile("Magento_Theme::html/header-style/" . $headerStyle . ".phtml"));
?>
<div style='color:red; font-size: 50%;'><p><span>Header Style Type : <?php echo $headerStyle . ".phtml (edited in : " . __FILE__ . ")" ?></span></p></div>
<?php
if ($_config->getAdvanced('show_newsletter_popup')) {
    echo $block->getChildHtml('form.subscribe.popup');
}
?>

<?php if ($_config->getGeneral('menu_ontop') == 1) { ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        require([
            'jquery'
        ], function ($) {
            $window = $(window);
            if ($('.header-bottom').length) {
                menu_offset_top = $('.header-bottom').offset().top;

                function processScroll() {
                    var scrollTop = $window.scrollTop();
                    if (scrollTop >= menu_offset_top) {
                        $('.header-bottom').addClass('menu-on-top');
                        $('body').addClass('body-on-top');
                    } else if (scrollTop <= menu_offset_top) {
                        $('.header-bottom').removeClass('menu-on-top');
                        $('body').removeClass('body-on-top');
                    }
                }

                processScroll();
                $window.scroll(function () {
                    processScroll();
                });
            }
        });
    </script>
<?php } ?>
```

> `app/design/frontend/Sm/market/Magento_Theme/templates/html/header-style/header-2.phtml`

```
<?php echo "Type of header-style : " . get_class($block); ?>
<?php $welcomeMessage = $block->getWelcome(); ?>

<div class="header-container header-style-2">
    <div class="header-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row row-topheader">
                <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-3 customer-action-header">
                    <div class="customer-action-hd">
                        <span class="welcome-text">

                            <span class="greet welcome" data-bind="scope: 'customer'">
                                **<!-- ko if: customer().fullname  -->
                                <span data-bind="text: new String('<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Welcome, %1!', '%1')); ?>').replace('%1', customer().firstname)">
                                </span>
                                <!-- /ko -->
                                <!-- ko ifnot: customer().fullname  -->
                                <span data-bind="html:'<?= $block->escapeHtml($welcomeMessage) ?>'"></span>
                                <!-- /ko -->**
                            </span>
                            <script type="text/x-magento-init">
                            {
                                "*": {
                                    "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": {
                                        "components": {
                                            "customer": {
                                                "component": "Magento_Customer/js/view/customer"
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            </script>

                        </span>

                        <?php
                        $login_customer = $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Customer\Block\Account\Customer');
                        ?>

                        <?php if ($login_customer->customerLoggedIn()) { ?>
                            <a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('customer/account/logout') ?>"
                               title="<?php echo __('Logout') ?>"><?php echo __('Logout') ?></a>
                        <?php } else { ?>
                            <a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('customer/account/create') ?>"
                               title="<?php echo __('Create Your Account') ?>"><?php echo __('Join Free') ?></a> <?php echo __('or') ?>
                            <a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('customer/account/login') ?>"
                               title="<?php echo __('Sign In') ?>"><?php echo __('Sign in') ?></a>
                        <?php } ?>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-lg-7 col-md-9 header-top-links">
                    <?php echo $block->getChildHtml('currency-header'); ?>
                    <?php echo $block->getChildHtml('language-header'); ?>
                    <?php echo $block->getChildHtml('toplinks-header'); ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="header-middle">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-2 logo-header">
                    <?php echo $block->getChildHtml('logo_theme'); ?>
                </div>

                <div class="col-lg-10 header-middle-right">
                    <div class="middle-right-content">
                        <div class="main-megamenu">
                            <?php echo $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Cms\Block\Block')->setBlockId('megamenu-horizontal')->toHtml(); ?>
                        </div>

                        <div class="minicart-header">
                            <div class="minicart-content">
                                <?php echo $block->getChildHtml('cart-header'); ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="header-bottom">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="navigation-mobile-container">
                    <?php echo $block->getChildHtml('navigation.mobile'); ?>
                </div>

                <div class="col-lg-3 sidebar-megamenu">
                    <div class="megamenu-content-sidebar">
                        <div class="btn-megamenu">
                            <a href="javascript:void(0)"
                               title="<?php echo __('All Categories') ?>"><?php echo __('All Categories') ?></a>
                        </div>

                        <div class="menu-ver-content">
                            <?php
                            if ($_config->getGeneral('menu_style') == 'megamenu') {
                                echo $block->getChildHtml('navigation-header-megamenu');
                            } else {
                                echo $block->getChildHtml('navigation-header');
                            }
                            ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-lg-9 searchbox-header">
                    <?php echo $block->getChildHtml('search-header-pro'); ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Corrupted file. show full code

Comment: What do you mean corrupted?  Because I cut off the `escapeHtml part for if: customer().fullname`?   In that sense its not 'corrupted'. I copied it from the console so it cut off, but will update with the full html content.

Comment: @SohelRana I updated it as requested, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After going to the wrong rabbit-hole, like trying to determine why `customer()` is used when it can clearly be empty, I eventually scrapped that idea and looked for something else.  It is much simpler than I anticipated - but quite frustrating regardless.

*I will remove all the unneeded code on my question on request, but I just left it there because a user requested me to show all code - 'because corrupted code'  The original question only showed the important part (which I have now shown here)*.

This issue is related to how knockout seems to not correctly handle (') single quote characters in some theme templates.

So assume your default welcome message is : **Welcome to XYZ' store**

The quote character in here causes the issue when the syntax is like below:

If your template has this:

```
<!-- ko ifnot: customer().fullname -->
<span data-bind="html:'<?= $block->escapeHtml($welcomeMessage) ?>'"></>
<!-- /ko -->
```

Change to this:

```
<!-- ko ifnot: customer().fullname -->
<span data-bind='html:"<?= $block->escapeHtml($welcomeMessage) ?>"'></>
<!-- /ko -->
```

Notice I swapped the single quote and double quote positions such that the double quotes are inside, so that in effect does this:

`' " ' " '`

Instead of:

`" ' ' ' "`

I am positive **anywhere (other templates)** where knockout data-bind is used with PHP `escapeHtml()` or where quote characters are present will have this issue.